# Splitting up MVC EditorFor for a list of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I'm trying to make an app where you can create forms for event registrations and such. I have a Form model that has an ICollection of Fields. Fields is abstract and derives things like Checkbox or TextInput and such. I've got it so the polymorphic behavior is working for my list of fields and I can get EditorFor templates for each kind of field so that I can do EditorFor on the whole list and it will generate the list with the correct template.

This is great and very easy with the entity framework, but my problem is that I want to be able to do some rendering logic between each field that is rendered on the screen. The fields are supposed to be rendered to a row/column grid and each Field has as properties Row / Size.
The only way I've figured out how to use the EditorFor templates on the list of fields is like this

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.EditorFor(form => form.Fields)
</div>
```

But I need to be able to have some kind of loop instead where I have control of where that template is getting rendered.. For instance they are sorted by row so I can check to see if we're still adding fields to the same row or if I need to create a new row.

If I had to solve this by tomorrow I'd just render it as static html divs and then move it around using jQuery but I feel like that's a terrible way. Another way would be to store the current row we're in in a Viewbag but then for each Field's template (like 12) I'd be just copying the same logic code...

Any better ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

EditorFor uses Tampletes that are store in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates. You can there define your own tamplates for your type or override existing.
Check this repo:
https://github.com/danmalcolm/mvc-razor-display-and-editor-templates/tree/master/src/DemoMvcApp/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

I think in your case, you want to override Object.cshtml
Like there:
https://github.com/danmalcolm/mvc-razor-display-and-editor-templates/blob/master/src/DemoMvcApp/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml
Am I right?

Comment: No I already have the correct Editor templates for my derived types that get rendered correctly for the correct type of field.

The problem is I need to not render the whole list of fields from templates at one time. I need to be able to render just one EditorFor template, then do some logic, then do the next template.

Comment: So you need Editor template for your list?

Comment: Ya that's what I've found is going to be the easiest solution. I found the source code for the default Collection template in the MVC source and it does exactly what I need (looping over each list item individually and calling EditorFor on it). So I'm going to basically take that code in my own template file and add my rendering logic in the inner loop and then instead of calling EditorFor(Model.Fields) I'll call EditorFor(Model.Fields, "MyCustomEditorTemplate")

Comment: And the easiest solutions are the best;)
You can also add [UIHint("MyCustomEditorTemplate")] attribute in your model.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution was just to loop on the rows in my main view. I store the current row index in ViewBag and then in the Editor templates I check if Model.Row == ViewBag.CurrRow. I don't really like this because I'd be looping through all of the templates for the fields for every row I have.

I think the permanent solution will be a custom ViewModel that has the Fields split up into Rows so I can have an Editor template for each row.

I also just found out that the EditorFor call on Model.Fields isn't actually calling EditorFor on all of the fields, it's calling it on the ICollection type, which in turn calls of the Field Editor templates. So I am pretty sure I can just make my own ICollection EditorTemplate that has the Row logic I need.